# i am trying to make a program that uses code from a text file to make classes

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a level editor that puts the level into a text file. Then I want my game to use that text file to reconstruct the level from the editor.
I want to make it so that I do not have to manually construct levels object by object.

I have tried to read files line by line and call each line, I've tried to use python files to do this, I have even tried an os solution from another question but nothing has worked.

```
class object:
    def __init__(self,name,colour,x,y,w,h,tag):
        self.colour = colour
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

platform = object("platform",gray,20,386,76,10,'movable')
floor =  object("floor",gray,-999999,display_height,999999999,500,0)
box = object("box",yellow,238,0,38,38,0)
ent_list = [floor,platform,box]
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What is not working? Your code does not include reading or writing to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to make a level editor that saved objects in text then the game would load that. but then i discovered pickling and that fixed everything